# Iterate through the linked list of ifaddr

Tags: c, networking, linked-list

```
struct ifaddrs {
    struct ifaddrs  *ifa_next;
    char        *ifa_name;
    unsigned int     ifa_flags;
    struct sockaddr *ifa_addr;
    struct sockaddr *ifa_netmask;
    struct sockaddr *ifa_dstaddr;
    void        *ifa_data;
}; 


struct ifaddrs *addrs,*tmp;

if(getifaddrs(&addrs) != 0) {
    perror("getifaddrs");
    return 1;
}

for(tmp = addrs; tmp ; tmp = tmp->ifa_next) {

}
```

I have seen this code of `getifaddrs` getting the results in `ifaddrs`. But the Iteration

for loop is lopping through all the interfaces it can find.

```
for(tmp = addrs; tmp ; tmp = tmp->ifa_next) {

}
```

The question is I don't see how `tmp->ifa_next` pointer incremented or going to the next link.

Comment: It is not incremented, it is just another pointer on each iteration. Try adding `fprintf(stderr, "%p -> %p\n", tmp, tmp->ifa_next);` inside the loop body and you will see.

Comment: because of `tmp = tmp->ifa_next`

Comment: BTW: there is no doubly linked list involved. Are you confused by the pointer-to-pointer ?

Answer (score 1):

It's saying while `tmp` is not `NULL` (has a value), to set `tmp` equal to `tmp->next`. So consider each loop. Below shows what happens on each iteration.

```
tmp = addrs;
tmp = tmp->next; ( tmp->next is equal to addrs->next)
tmp = tmp->next; ( tmp->next is equal to addrs->next->next because tmp is equal to addrs->next)
```

etc...

Eventually, `tmp->next` is `NULL` and sets `tmp` equal to `NULL`, at which point the loop is exited.

To further draw out this analogy (it took me a long time to get how linked lists work):

If we have a linked list of { `1`, `2`, `3`, `NULL` }, use the above loop on this collection. Below is pseudo-code to give a better idea.

```
tmp = 1;
tmp = tmp->next; // 1->next = 2, so tmp = 2
tmp = tmp->next; // 2->next = 3, so tmp = 3
tmp = tmp->next; // 3->next = null, so tmp = null
exit
```